# TrueNAS Scale update error: mount failed: Operation not permitted.​

Tags: permissions, updates, truenas

I am unable to update from TrueNAS-SCALE-22.02.4 to Bluefin. Independently on whether I let the GUI download the update or whether I provide it manually, I get the following Error:

**[EFAULT] Invalid update image file. Please, re-download update. Error: mount: /tmp/tmp72zlj55e: mount failed: Operation not permitted.​**

The file is certainly OK, it seems to be a permission issue. The /tmp folder has all permissions.